# Position relative to screen size

Tags: css, size

before I start to explain my problem, I just wan't to say that even if this subject already exist I haven't found any solution working, it has been 1 week that this problem is now blocking, I really need help. So the problem is that I started to create a website and I tried it on different screen resolution, but it only work on mine, on different the elements are going crazy and do strange things, each go on the other etc...
Here's my code :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    src: url(Comfortaa-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
 font-family: Comfort;
 src: url(ChampEtLimou.ttf);
}
body
{
 background-color : rgb(255,255,255);
}
.titre3
{
 color : #0183c0;
 font-family : Comfortaa;
 position:  fixed;
 font-size :50px;
 z-index:10; 
 left : 43.2%;
 top:-6%;

}
.titre1
{
 color : #6597ed;
 font-family : Comfortaa;
 position:  fixed;
 left : 43.2%;
 top:3%;
 font-size : 30px;
 z-index:10;
}
.bacc
{
 font-family : Comfortaa;
 position : fixed;
 left : 45%;
 top : 12%;
 color:#ffffff;
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #7a8eb9;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #7a8eb9;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #7a8eb9;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #196499), color-stop(1, #1a6ba1));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #196499 5%, #1a6ba1 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #196499 5%, #1a6ba1 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #196499 5%, #1a6ba1 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #196499 5%, #1a6ba1 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #196499 5%, #1a6ba1 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#196499', endColorstr='#1a6ba1',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#196499;
 border:1px solid #314179;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:11px 23px;
 z-index:10;
}
.bacc:hover
{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #1a6ba1), color-stop(1, #196499));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #1a6ba1 5%, #196499 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1a6ba1 5%, #196499 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #1a6ba1 5%, #196499 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #1a6ba1 5%, #196499 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #1a6ba1 5%, #196499 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1a6ba1', endColorstr='#196499',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#1a6ba1;
}
.bacc:active
{

}
.ball 
{
 position: fixed;
    width : 2.7%;
 height:5%;
 left:40%;
 top:2%;
 z-index:10;
}
.immenu
{
 position:relative;
 top:15em;
 left:3em;
 width:30%;
 height:30%;
 z-index:2;
 padding: 8px 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 3px 3px 13px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}
.safalogo
{
 position:fixed;
 top:5%;
 left:5%;
 width:6%;
 height:5%;
 z-index:10;
}
.sanologo
{
 position:fixed;
 top:5%;
 left:12%;
 width:6%;
 height:8%;
 z-index:10;
}
.banner
{
 position:relative;
 top:-7em;
 left:-5em;
 width:100em;
 height:25em;
 z-index:0;
}
.voile
{
 position:relative;
 top:-32.2em;
 left:-1em;
 width:100em;
 height:25em;
 z-index:1;
 opacity:0.5;
}
.speechtitre
{
 color : white;
 font-family : Comfort;
 position:  relative;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-top:0;
 left : -1.7em;
 top:-30em;
 font-size : 30px;
 z-index:1;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.speechtex
{
 color : white;
 font-family : Comfort;
 position:  relative;
 left : 29em;
 top:-45em;
 font-size : 20px;
 z-index:1;
}
.ligne
{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:0.2%;
 top:20%;
 left:0%;
 z-index:10;
}
.faceblogo
{
 position:fixed;
 width:3.8%;
 height:6%;
 left:90%;
 top:6%;
 z-index:10;
}
.bfixe
{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 top:0%;
 left:0%;
 z-index:9;
 opacity:0.75;
}
body
{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding:auto;
 border:auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kibera Black Stars</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <style type="text/css">a:link{text-decoration:none}</style>
</head>
<body>
 <p class="titre3">Kibera</p>
 <P  class="titre1">BlackStars</P>
 <img src="images/ball.png" alt="ballon" class="ball">
 <a href="Site.html" class="bacc">Accueil</a>
 <img src="images/safalogo.png" alt="safalogo" class="safalogo">
 <img src="images/sanologo.png" alt="sanologo" class="sanologo">
 <img src="images/ligne.jpg" alt="ligne" class="ligne">
 <img src="images/bannierfixe.jpg" alt="bannierfixe" class="bfixe">
 <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BLACKSTARSKIBERA" target="_blank"><img src="images/faceblogo.png" alt="faceblogo" class="faceblogo"></a></p>
 <img src="images/immenu.jpg" alt="immenu" class="immenu">
 <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="banner" class="banner">
 <img src="images/voile.jpg" alt="voile" class="voile">
 <p align="center" class="speechtitre">Faut mettre un titre la !</p>
 <p class="speechtex">Faut mettre un texte ici !</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Please be more specific about the issue. The post only have a wage title and no details inside the description.

Comment: Okay sorry, the problem is that when I resize the page with my mouse, all the elements move from their original place and are going on the others, it became illisible, I don't know how to resolve that, let me try to get a screen.

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2018-23-1-1528111020-dqsdqsdqsdqsdqsd.png

Comment: @GreenTree with the above give code, cant help you in anyway, can you post your complete code along with linked CSS files in JSFiddle or codepen.

Comment: But this is the comple code, there is nothing more to execute the site x)

Comment: Oooh yeah you are right, how can I do for the images ?

Comment: Your problem might be coming from the position property you are using

Comment: Like how can I resolve it ? Do I need to recode all ?

Comment: can you show how it should look, because if I only see how it's not supposed to look it's kinda hard to help

Comment: keep in my mind that when using position:fixed element goes out of the flow of the website, like if it was on top

Comment: Yeah sorry : https://www.noelshack.com/2018-23-1-1528113714-sqsqsqsqqs.png

Comment: @GreenTree can you share the code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">`  within the Style.css ?

Comment: I already sent it x)

Answer (score 0):

You use fixed positions. This couse your problem. You should use media queries for different screen sizes. I suggest you to use bootstrap or something similar has a grid system. Bootstrap has grid system for xs, xm, md, xl etc. screen sizes. You can hide some elements for smaller screens, too.

For example, we want four divs side by side for large screens. On medium screens, we want to show three of them side by side.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle demo:

For more info visit: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I didn't really understand sorry, are you french ? Because if you are maybe you can explain it to me in this language, i'll more understand x)

Comment: Sorry, I'M not French :). So, You use `position: fixed;` in css. This fix the element to the given point. For example, if I use this code:
`.class {position:fixed;top:30px;left:30px;}`
it fix my elemet to a point away from left top corner by 30x30 pixels. But, if you use bootstrap framework for styling the positions, you can make the elemets responsive easily. You can set an element only for large screens for example. That element will not be shown to the medium and small screens. You can visit the bootstrap site for more and acurate info. They write better English documentation then me :)

Comment: Thank you but the problem is all elements are necessary in my site, I need that they all can be seen even if you have a smaller screen ^^

Comment: You can reposition them for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Just recreated the layout of with some basic place holders. Maybe you can use the base structure and extend/build on top of this.

Preview at JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b4vez5qx/

NOTE : This is not responsive and its just elastic layout.

HTML

```
<header>
<div class="logo">logo</div>
  site title
  <div class="facebook">FaceBook</div>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="imgCont"><img src="via.placeholder.com/250x200/"> </div>
    <div class="headText">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <div>
        Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:arial}
header{border-bottom:1px solid blue; text-align:center; height:50px; background:#f4f4f4; padding:25px 10px 0 20px;}
header div{display:inline-block;}

.logo{float:left}
.facebook{float:right}
.sitetitle{}

.main{background:#0e1436; height:250px;}
.imgCont{padding:10px;float:left}
.imgCont img{border:8px solid #1b344b}

.headText{padding:10px; color:#fff;}
```

Hope this helps